# Additional lint rules in Android

Tags: android, jenkins, android-lint

I want to include some additional lint rules in my Android project. And by additional rules, i mean that i just want to include some extra rules from the list given in Android Studio( Pic attached)[image]

From the picture, i want to include the non-checked items also. Now i can do this very easily by checking the checkbox in Android Studio, but i want to do it for my Jenkins setup.

So is there any such XML file in which i can write the rules and just include it and it will run or do i have to go [this](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules) hard way. I feel that there is an easy way to do it because it just a pre-defined rule and not any custom rule that i will be writing.

EDIT:
For Android lint rules, i can create a lint file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
<issue id="HardcodedText" severity="error" />
</lint>
```

But there is no such id/keyword for Java/C++/Other lint rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules that we see in Analyze->Inspect code are not actually same as the Android lint rules. These are the rules that is run by insepct.sh file in Android studio only when we do `Inspect code` and that doesnt run when we run or build the project.

In contrast,when we run the `lint` command in gradle,it doesnt check the code according to these rules(from the pic). It actually checks against the original Android lint rules(`lint --list`). So the only way to write additional lint rules is to go the hard way as specified in my question. Or one can use [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/google_style.html) to specify some fair amount of rules.